# What are all the portlet classes in Spring mvc?

Tags: java, spring, web-applications, spring-mvc, portlet

In Spring MVC there seem to be two parallel class hierarchies, one with portlet, one without.

What is that? Why is it so and what should I use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because

> In addition to supporting conventional
>   (servlet-based) Web development,
>   Spring also supports JSR-168 Portlet
>   development. As much as possible, the
>   Portlet MVC framework is a mirror
>   image of the Web MVC framework, and
>   also uses the same underlying view
>   abstractions and integration
>   technology.

The [Spring documentation (Chapter 16. Portlet MVC Framework)](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/portlet.html) provides more information about the differences.

To answer your last question: you should use the [Portlet MVC framework](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/portlet.html) if you are developing portlets (web applications to be deployed in a portal). If you are developing conventional web applications you should use the [Web MVC framework](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/mvc.html).

Answer (score 2):

You mean as opposed to servlet?  The portlet MVC framework is specifically for development of JSR-168 (maybe JSR-286 too? not sure) portlets.  There is a separate portlet hierarchy because the portlet MVC workflow differs from the servlet MVC workflow.

If you're developing a portlet, you want the portlet MVC framework.  Otherwise, the Servlet MVC framework is what you need and you don't need to worry about the portlet stuff.