# What does Servlet API and Portlet API mean?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

[This](http://blog.springsource.org/2007/11/14/annotated-web-mvc-controllers-in-spring-25/) link says that Spring MVC is essentially a request dispatcher framework, with a Servlet API variant and Portlet API variant.

So then, what exactly does this mean? What kind of environment do these two approaches provide?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are all the portlet classes in Spring mvc?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/722383/what-are-all-the-portlet-classes-in-spring-mvc)

Comment: see this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1480528/what-is-the-difference-between-a-portlet-and-a-servlet

Comment: @ManishSharma : Oh Yes. I wanted to ask the same thing. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that Spring will start and wait for requests, and it will redirect the requests received to your code.

You can implement your code either as servlets or portlets, usually extending/implementing one of the classes/interfaces provided by such API. Spring will provide mechanisms so you can forget the gory details (TCP, managing URLs) and concentrate in your code.